# How to change cascading behavior of react-checkbox-tree package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, data-structures, checkbox, treeview

I am using react-checkbox-tree to implement a users dropdown. Each users have certain deals which I need to display. However the cascading behavior is not per my requirement. Clicking on parent node selects/deselects all the child nodes which is fine and when child node is deselected then parent node also gets deselected(if that parent have only one child). I don't want this to happen even if the parent have only one child deselecting the child should not deselect the parent because that parent have it's own deals which I want to display in UI.
Example: Clicking on Bala selects all it's child nodes(as expected)

[image]

and deselecting it deselects all it's child nodes(as expected)

[image]

but selecting/deselecting Beil should selects/deselects all it's children(i.e Jairam, Laxman, etc) but should not select or deselect it's parent node i.e Bala.
There is one prop called noCascade which stops the cascading behavior which I can't use. I need cascading but it should be only one way i.e on children(towards downward) and not parent(towards upward). Basically I don't want any half or intermediate check for a node.
Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

[image]